# How to export a PowerPoint shape as a good quality image file

Tags: vba, graphics, powerpoint

I am trying to generate a few hundred basic graphics where the shape text and background color is based on a text string.

For this i have chosen to use PowerPoint, because i feel that the image styling is quite comprehensive for my function. The only program that i know how to do this is Adobe Photoshop, however i do not have that software.

I have got the export image function to work, however the image quality of the exported graphic is terrible

How could i get this done with a better image processor?

As can be seen, i have a powerpoint slide with a textbox to hold the stringvalues (Rectangle 5) and my "shape" which will be styled by the two RGB values in the text string.
the string value has the following format (pipe delimited)

- Textbox 4.Name | Rounded Rectangle 7.Color | Rounded Rectangle 3.Color

[image]

Code used:

```
Private Sub btnProcess_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim StringsArray As Variant
Dim StringItems As Variant
    ' Call getlines to break all lines into separate records in stringsarray
    StringsArray = getlines()
    For i = 0 To UBound(StringsArray)
       StringItems = Split(StringsArray(i), "|")
       ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("TextBox 4").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = StringItems(0)
       ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 7").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = StringItems(1)
       ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 3").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = StringItems(2)
       ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("Group 6").Export "C:\temp\file.emf", ppShapeFormatEMF, 150, 150, ppRelativeToSlide
    Next i
End Sub

Function getlines() As Variant
Dim mylines As Variant
Dim mytext As String
    mytext = ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("Rectangle 5").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    mylines = Split(mytext, vbCr)
    getlines = mylines
End Function
```

Comment: What version of PPT are you using?  And how are you evaluating the quality of the EMF?  If you're not already doing so, import it back into PowerPoint (Insert picture from file).

Comment: Using Office 2010 - yes, good question, the graphics i am generating (from the ppt shape) are about 115X70 so they are small, probably too small!... (that my be my problem huh?) using EMF creates files that are over 1.5MB. so that would probably take up too much space for me.

Comment: Ok... so increasing the size of the graphic on the ppt slide improved the image quality (ofcourse!). The program consuming the images re-sizes each image itself, so it all worked perfectly.  ... now how do i close the question?

Comment: I guess you'd want to describe how you solved the problem in an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector graphics based PPT object as seen on the PowerPoint slide is not affected by the scale so at all zoom level the object will not appear distorted.

I could not find a way to output the object graphic as a true Metafile even the ppShapeFormatEMF format does not generate a vector based EMF, just a much larger image.

My best solution at the end, was to increase the base size of the PPT object and export the shape object using the ppShapeFormatPNG format thereby increasing the level of detail of the image.

Kinda Obvious.

[image]

Comment: Just a nightcap before putting it to bed:  likely you weren't able to get a true vector-based EMF because effects like the soft shadows are image-based, not vector, as are the edge treatments, so PPT probably opted to output the result as a bitmap wrapped up in your EMF.  IIRC, that means you get the bitmap portion as an uncompressed BMP, which'd account for the size of the resulting file.

Comment: ok, yes, good advice, i will try to make a simple graphic to see if the emf file is correctly made.. thanks for the help!